# Ldap error code 32 while adding user to ldap

Tags: java, ldap, spring-ldap

I need to add a new user entry to my ldap. Following is my code:

```
     javax.naming.Name name = new DistinguishedName("cn=" + userName +",ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org");


     Attribute objectClass = new BasicAttribute("objectClass");
        {
         objectClass.add("top");
         objectClass.add("inetOrgPerson");
         objectClass.add("person");
         objectClass.add("organizationalPerson");
        }
        Attributes userAttributes = new BasicAttributes();
        userAttributes.put(objectClass);
        userAttributes.put("cn", userName);
        userAttributes.put("sn", "abctest");
        userAttributes.put(ATTRIBUTE_USER_PASSWORD, password);
        LdapTemplate ldapTemplate = (LdapTemplate) SpringBeanFactory
                .getBean("ldapTemplate");
        ldapTemplate.bind(name, null, userAttributes);
```

Although when this piece of code is executed I get the following exception:

```
 org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object];       
 nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: 
 [LDAP: error code 32 -      No Such Object]; remaining name 'cn=myname,ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org'
```

I am following the example specified at http://kaustuvmaji.blogspot.in/2014/12/simple-example-of-spring-ldap.html for the code. Can someone help me in understanding the root cause for this error or the right code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that the path `ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org` doesn't exist in your LDAP tree, so you cannot create a child at that path.

If you specified a base path for your `ContextSource` that should be omitted from all DNs in code, as all paths will be relative to the specified base.

Comment: I picked up the path from the LDAP tree itself using Apache Directory Studio. For eg: another existing entry has DN = "cn=newName,ou=Users,dc=wso2,dc=org". Could the case(uppercase/lowercase) of the terms in the path be a problem? Is there a way to verify the path?

Comment: Updated answer with tip on base path

Comment: Thanks @marthursson !! Removing the base path from the DN worked for me.