# [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100241, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ldap, ldap-query

I am trying to add a user to an Active directory group using Spring Boot with the following code.

```
public boolean addMemberToGroup(String groupName, Person p) {
    boolean status = false;
    Name groupDn = buildGroupDn(groupName);
    Name personDn = buildPersonDn(p);

    try {
        DirContextOperations ctx = ldapTemplate.lookupContext(groupDn);
        ctx.addAttributeValue(UNIQUE_MEMBER, personDn);
        ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(ctx);
               
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logException
    }
    return status;
}

private Name buildGroupDn(String groupName) {
    return LdapNameBuilder.newInstance(baseLdapPath)
            .add("OU", "ghtc")
            .add("OU", "IT")
            .add("OU", "Groups")           
                    
            .add("CN", groupName)
            .build();
}
```

`baseLdapPath = DC=emea,DC=testdir,DC=net` and this is added in the application.properties file.

But when `ldapTemplate.lookupContext(groupDn);` executes, following exception occurs:

> nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100241, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
> 'DC=emea,DC=testdir,DC=net'
> remaining name 'CN=GroupAMC,OU=Groups,OU=IT,OU=ghtc,DC=emea,DC=testdir,DC=net'*

I have verified that the distinguished name of the group is `CN=GroupAMC,OU=Groups,OU=IT,OU=ghtc,DC=emea,DC=testdir,DC=net`

What am I missing here?

Comment: we can't see the code that is being passed into this procedure, but are you sure the group name is "the DN of the corresponding group, including the groupSearchBase" ( https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/userdetails/LdapUserDetailsManager.html#buildGroupDn-java.lang.String- )

Comment: I have added the buildGroupDn code as well. Is it something to do with setting scope as SUBTREE_SCOPE. Because when I search using SearchControls I am able to find the group when I set the scope as SUBTREE_SCOPE

Comment: just for curiosities sake, are you sure that "baseLdapPath" is set to "DC=emea,DC=testdir,DC=net" ?  can you do the same search using ldapsearch?

Comment: Yes, I have verified it. I can search the group as well. Is it something to do with the access? The credentials for my LDAP server do not have write access yet. I thought with read access I should be able to execute lookupContext and should face an exception when I modifyAttributes

Comment: if you can use anonymous lookups with ldapsearch, then it shouldn't be a problem. If you can't then yes, that is probably your problem. I was asking you to check because of the "best match of" bit, but I think it's doing it correctly

Comment: Okay. I have tried to look up generated distinguishedName in LDAP tool and I am able to find the group. It is strange that with the same name I am not able to fetch it in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the error using the below link
[Ldap error code 32 while adding user to ldap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493845/ldap-error-code-32-while-adding-user-to-ldap)

The issue was with the baseDn while building groupName. Removing the baseLdapPath fixed the issue

```
private Name buildGroupDn(String groupName) {
        return LdapNameBuilder.newInstance()
                .add("OU", "ghtc")
                .add("OU", "IT")
                .add("OU", "Groups")           
                
                .add("CN", groupName)
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: glad you found a fix!